# Ansible include_task search for file does not appear to be looking down documented search list

Tags: ansible

Ansible documentation seems to suggest that it searches for tasks files in the current role tasks folder, then up the chain of 'parent' role folders, and finally the playbook folder.  ([Resolving local relative paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbook_pathing.html#resolving-local-relative-paths)). I'm not seeing this behavior.

I have a role that is trying to call a 'callback' tasks file from the parent role, but the callback tasks file in the parent role's tasks folder is not being found.

In a very much simplified example that reduces to only relevant code, here is my scenario.

*playbook.yml*

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
  - parent
```

*parent/tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
---
- include_role:
    role: child
```

*child/tasks/main.yml*

```yaml
---
- include_tasks:
    file: 'callback.yml'
```

*parent/tasks/callback.yml*

```yaml
---
- debug:
    msg: "HELLO from callback.yml"
```

When invoking the playbook, via `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`, I expect the playbook to call the parent, which calls the child, which calls the callback task list - which should be found in the parent role's tasks folder.  I expect to see the `HELLO` message.
Instead, the following error appears:

```json
TASK [child : include_tasks] *******************
task path: /home/cloud-user/test/roles/child/tasks/main.yml:5
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {
    "reason": "Could not find or access '<path-to-playbook-folder>/tasks/parent_tasks.yml' on the Ansible Controller."
}
```

Running with `-vvvvv` doesn't reveal much helpful information.
Dumping the `ansible_search_path` variable prior to the `include_tasks` revealed:

```json
TASK [child : debug] ******************
task path: /home/cloud-user/test/roles/child/tasks/main.yml:2
ok: [host] => {
    "ansible_search_path": [
        "/home/cloud-user/test/roles/child",
        "/home/cloud-user/test/roles/parent",
        "/home/cloud-user/test/roles/child/tasks",
        "/home/cloud-user/test"
    ]
}
```

I also tried including the filename *tasks/callback.yml*, and including variations of a fileglob lookup (i.e., `include_tasks: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'callback.yml') }}`).

Am I interpreting the searchlist description in the documentation incorrectly?  Or should Ansible be finding my callback tasks file in the parent role's tasks folder?

Comment: How is your role dependency defined between `child` and `parent`?

Comment: Everything is shown - the playbook runs the role 'parent' via roles section of playbook, and 'parent' runs the role 'child' via dynamic 'include_role'.  The role child runs the task 'include_tasks' with a variable passed down from the parent role naming the tasks file which is in parent's own tasks folder.  I expected the child's include_tasks to search up the chain (dumping the ansible parent role paths magic var did show the parent role in the chain.)

Comment: Then, as the pointed by the `ansible_search_path` variable, the task is looking in `/home/cloud-user/test/roles/parent` but not in `/home/cloud-user/test/roles/parent/tasks`.

Comment: I saw that, but then I would have expected tasks/callback.yml to work.  The lookup appears to find that tasks exists in parent but doesn't contain callback.yml, and so it stops there, rather than continuing down the list to see if something further down the list might match.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem IMHO, the documentation is not accurate. I notified #ansible-docs at [IRC](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/community/communication.html#ansible-community-on-irc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbook_pathing.html#resolving-local-relative-paths) is not accurate. In the first paragraph, it says that the parent role (that includes ... the current role) will be searched:

> Ansible will try to find that file first in the current task’s role, then **in other roles that included or depend on the current role**, then relative to the file in which the task is defined, and finally relative to the current play.

In the third paragraph, it says the parent role won't be searched:

> Ansible will **only search within a role if you actually included it with an include_role or import_role task or a dependency**.

I think, that the first statement is implicitly valid for [lookup plugins and some paths used in action plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbook_pathing.html#task-paths):

> paths passed to lookup plugins and some paths used in action plugins such as the “src” path for the template and copy modules

The second statement should say that it is valid for tasks, I think.

Comment: Seen.  I think this is suggesting that if since parent is included from the playbook by "roles" it is not searched, but if there were another level and parent had been included by "include_role" it would be searched.  I'll try that out tomorrow.